# UITabBarController moreNavigationController item image (UITableViewCell image)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm using the `UITabBarController`'s built in moreViewController. In the main tab bar I'm using original images instead of template images:

```
tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Which works fine. When I go to the moreNavigationController, the images are just blue'd out (it's using them as template images).

It says in Apple's documentation that the moreNavigationController is not meant to be customizatable. However these are just standard UITableViewCells which can totally support an original image.

Any ideas?

I want to use the built in one for its ability to rearrange the tabs. I could roll my own if necessary (won't be simple), but I'd sure like to leverage what's built in.

[image]